# Convert introspection result to SDL format in Go

Tags: go, graphql

I can fetch the result of introspection from remote graphQL server, I want now to transform that result (JSON format) to SDL format.
An [example](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/backend/schema-design/three-ways-to-represent-your-graphql-schema/) of what I need but written in JavaScript

thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is with https://github.com/CDThomas/graphql-json-to-sdl

Since it's a node JS application, you could set it up, install it, etc then run it from go like this

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
    jsonFilePath := "./schema.json"
    outputFilePath := "./schema.graphql"
    comm := fmt.Sprintf("graphql-json-to-sdl %s %s", jsonFilePath, outputFilePath)
    sourcePath := "~/.bashrc"
    cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "source "+sourcePath+" ; "+comm)
    cmd.Stdout = &stdout
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    outStr, errStr := string(stdout.Bytes()), string(stderr.Bytes())
    fmt.Printf("out:\n%s\nerr:\n%s\n", outStr, errStr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it does the intended  but is not what I am looking for. I am limited to pure Golang code.